# Is my SDL / C++ program eating up too much RAM memoy?

Tags: c++, sdl

I've written a simple program, which renders the screen green and renders a .png image to the screen (which has hello world written on it). I am using a Window and a Texture class, and I have a main.cpp file. I deleting the pointers in the destructor, and I am using SDL's DestroyTexture/Window/etc functions as well. 
When I start my program, it eats up ~11MBs of RAM. I think it is too much, but I could be wrong. What do you say?

Comment: What's the resolution?

Comment: the screen res is 640x480, the images take up like 4kilobytes.

Comment: If you only had 640k RAM, then yes, 11 MB would be too much.

Comment: But it seems too much for a program this small.

Comment: @user3357969 I'm guessing that there is overhead for whatever libraries you are including, and in a system with only 4 GB, 11 MB is tiny.

Comment: are you using SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)? Maybe using only SDL_INIT_VIDEO would lower costs by using less features.

Comment: I am using SDL_INIT_VIDEO

Comment: It probably also matters whether you're using software rendering or hardware rendering.

Comment: I am using hardware rendering

Comment: I also wonder if it may have to do with what version of the standard libraries you're linking to. You might have better luck finding an answer by using a debugger to track allocations.

Comment: Also, unless PNG and SDL went back to 16 bits per pixel formats, you are using more than 4kb for the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal. Its is the "blind of poker", the bet you need to pay no matter what is in your hand, no matter your software.

You may think you are simple calling functions but there's a whole background behind it.

Calls to other functions, calls to SO functions who calls more and more.
All of this using shared libraries, who you didn't call but you need.

Answer (score -3):

If you have the feeling it's working too much to be this small, that maybe true if you're not limiting your framerate.

If your window can refresh itself 5000 times in a second (exactly because the program is so small) it will eat too much memory.

Read [this](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson14/) for a good explanation on how to calculate and limit framerate in your sdl program.

Comment: Probably because framerate and memory consumption have nothing to do together, unless obviously you're using some sort of garbage collection system, you don't manage your resources well and you keep creating objects every frame and they only get disposed after X seconds... then yes, more frames per second means more wasted memory until the cleanup pass.